# Determine the data types of a data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, rsqlite

I'm kinda new to R and SQL and I have loaded data into a dataframe using `dbConnect()` from the package RSQLite. How do I determine the data type of each column in the data frame?

Side question: How can I get database query results to make a xy plot?

Comment: If you want an elegant method, please do `lapply(your_data_frame, class)` This function is a condensed form of a looping, and it will iterate over a base class function `class()`. Unfortunately, I can't help you with SQL related side question, since I don't how it works :(

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when i apply `lapply()` for my data frame I got this error
Error in as.list.default(X) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: From the error I belive your object is not of type data.frame or matrix, are you sure your object is data.frame? You can check it using `class(variable_storing_dbcon())`. If it anyhing other than df or mat, than sorry `lapply` won't work. You can then do `str(variable_storing_dbcon())` to see underlying classes.

Comment: Sorry for not much help, but please take a look at this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxeRojFBIZo this guy answers most of your questions. You can then build on to your acquired knowledge. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciated your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at str & class function.

class(db_df) => Class of the object/dataframe

str(db_df)   => Data type of each column in the data-frame.